# What constitutes a correct sermon (khotba) of jumu'ah according the schools of fiqh?

Tags: fiqh, jumuah, khutbah

As far as I know all Muslims (correct me if I'm wrong) agree that the jumu'ah prayer consists of two sermons and a two raka' prayer.

I'd like to know what constitutes a correct khotba of jumua'ah according the different schools of fiqh (if possible name some evidences and references). And whether or how they differ between the first and second khotba (sermon).
(Of course an answer of a single school is welcome)